# IIS don't show Silverlight 5 application on work server in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, iis-7.5

My SL app shows correctly in all browsers (Opera, FF, IE) in all  web servers (embedded, IIS 7.5) on my develompment machine. But in work web server (IIS 7.5) no one browser show my SL app. No error, nothing - just empty place. But it contains all markup of my SL app:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="200px" height="40px">
          <param name="source" value="@Url.Content("~/Apps/SilverlightApplication1.xap")"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
</object>
```

In addition, on my development machine I have the "Setup SL app on this PC..." button in SL context menu, but not on my work server.

All IISs - on development and work server machines - have settings ".NET 4 FW" for app pool .NET version and integrated pipeline.

I can get the .xap file directly through the browser's address bar but can't get one through the HTML page.

It seems that the SL app just is not visible on my work server. How to fix it?

Addition. There is no any Silverlight development or client framework on the work server - can it be clue?

**UPDATE.** I changed data and type attributes in the object tag to "application/x-silverlight-app". Now the "invite to install SL" image appears instead of my SL app. But I already have the newest version of SL plugin, and while installing the SL the installer tells me about it.

Comment: How you browsed directly to the URL where the XAP file should reside? That should give you some clues.

Comment: I can't access to the Apps folder (error 403) but can access to the Apps/SilverlightApplication1.xap file.

Comment: Addition. There is no any Silverlight development or client framework on the work server - can it be clue?

Comment: Any server can serve up a XAP file... if the MIME type is registered. It is just a file and does not require any SDK or framework on the server (for the client side). Try putting the full URL into your param setting.

Comment: What do you mean "putting the full URL into your param setting"? I can access the XAP file through the browser's address string through the full URL of this XAP file - the save dialog appears.

Comment: Put the full "http://domain/Apps/SilverlightApplication1.xap" path in your `<param name="source" value ="http://domain/Apps/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>` to eliminate your relative path as the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting just a white screen then you should go into the silverlight.js and make it so the errors are thrown to some sort of message box that you can see.

If it's plain white there is an error of some sort going on, and if debug is essentially turned off in the settings (i.e don't show the user the error) then you'll not know what the issue is.

[EDIT]

Add .xap  application/x-silverlight-app as MIME type.

Comment: Not just a white screen - only the white (or empty) place instead of SL app, but the rest of the page works and sees well.

Comment: In the SL project I have a helper MVC project in which I have Silverlight.js file and scripts on the SL app host page. But I havn't this file and scripts in my site. Should I always include Silverlight.js file and scripts in my site, or it should be only for the test purposes?

Comment: I copied scripts to my site as in the helper MVC project - nothing changed.

Comment: You should publish the site, and then copy the whole publish contents to the server.

Comment: I think there are no any errors on the SL side, so there are no any error messages with these scripts. The IIS just won't to show the XAP file.

Comment: Have you added .xap to the mime types in IIS?

.xap as application/x-silverlight-app.

Comment: Yes, its MIME was there from the beginning.